# Error trying to open project from VisualStudioOnline

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I just started trying to use VSO for my test projects I work on at home. I think I've got that all configured up and working properly but now I'm looking to connect to VSO at work so that I can look at some of the sample code for use on my work projects. At work I'm connected to our enterprise TFS server.

What I tried was to open my VSO account and then I chose the project. From there I selected the open in Visual Studio option. That launched my local VS 2015 but then I got an error that I did not have access to my VSO account.

After doing some searching I saw where someone suggested to open the web browser inside of VS and connect. I went through those steps (open VS, Tools, Web Browser, VSO site, logged in, selected project, opened .sln file) and that opened the project in a separate instance of VS locally. I mapped the workspace to my local drive and did a Map & Get. This opened the project locally but it was not in Source Control (determined by the fact that there were no lock icons next to the files).

I was even able to open my local VS, choose the project, went to File | Source Control | Open from Server | saw and selected my VSO account | selected my the project and saw it get the files from the server. However, as soon as it tried to open the project after copying all the files I got the same "TF30063: You are not authorized to access VSOAccount\DefaultCollection".

Anyone have any suggestions on something I can try?

Comment: Did you tried connecting to the project from "Team Explorer\Manage Connections\Connect to team project"?

Comment: That looks like it worked. I had to then go bind the source control by using File | Source Control | Advanced | Change Source Control. I'm working through some other issues but I think this is going to work. I'll get back if it doesn't.

Comment: So far what @Eddie-MSFT showed seem to work for me. I had to go back in and connect to the project a couple times. It's like the connection gets lost after a little bit of idle time but that could also be something to do with my work's network. I was able to do a check-in after I resolved my conflicts. Now the test will be to see if I can do a Get Latest at home and see any new changes.

Comment: @Eddie-MSFT put this in an answer so I can vote it up for you.

Comment: OK, I have update it.

Comment: Just an update. It has to be work network related. I still can't connect 95% of that time on but every once in a while I get lucky. However, when I use my work laptop on my home network it works perfectly. Using Team Explorer | Manage Connections | Connect to Team Project is what works for me (at least when I have access).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to connect to the project from "Team Explorer\Manage Connections\Connect to team project".

If it still does not work, try following actions:

1. Log out your account.
2. Clear IE Cookies.
3. Clear TFS Cache. The cache folder usually locates in C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation. You may
   see several folders like 3.0, 4.0, 5.0 in it. Clean the Cache folder
   in these folders.

Answer (score 1):

Go to Help/Register Product in Visual Studio and make sure the account you need to access the VSO account is listed under All Accounts.

[image]

Comment: I guess I might be having something going on because of our work settings. When I try to add my account it comes back with a error that it can't authenticate me but I know I'm putting in the correct credentials. The message is coming back a 403 "Response status code does not indicate success" and it lists my companies LoginPage as where the message is coming from. My guess is they might have some port or something locked down. I'm sure this would be the correct place to fix it if I could.

Comment: Sounds likely to me.